# Twitter bootstrap Modal with Gmap on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I am including google map js in my **phtml** page and a twitter bootstrap model
but on Chrome it is not working. How does it affect ? Because black background is shown and does not go until I double click then I can't close the button in the model.

```
<button id="profile_btn_message" class="btn profile-btn"  href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
    <?php echo $this->translate('contact'); ?>
</button>
```

and my Modal Div is

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="text-center ">
            تنبيه
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body text-right font-bold" style="font-size: 18px;line-height: 25px;">
        عزيزي المستخدم
        <br />
         يمكنك الان مراسلة الطبيب لتحديد موعد للمراجعة او ارسال استفسار خاص لنفس الطبيب
        <br/>
        <span style="color: #F5517A">
            ملاحضة: 
        </span>
        : في حال لم تتضمن المراسلة للاحتمالات المذكورة اعلاه سوف يتم تحويلها كسؤال على الموقع او رفض المراسلة 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="message_cancle" class="btn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >اغلاق</button>
        <?php if (isset($this->location['location_id'])) {?>
        <button id="message_continue" class="btn pull-right margin-right-5px" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendEmail('<?php echo $this->escape($this->url(array('location_id' => $this->location['location_id']), 'ajaxMessageSend')); ?>');">استمرار </button>
        <?}?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will you please add your modal div code here?

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternate way of toggling a modal - by using JavaScript.

Include the following code snippet in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

Add an anchor tag for toggling the modal, and see if your modal works now:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"> <?php echo $this-     >translate('contact'); ?> </a>
```

PS - Do remember to include one of bootstrap.min.js or bootswatch.js file. Do NOT include both.

Hope this works :-)